Why don't the selectedTextColor and selectedBgColor contain any value?
Here is my code. It appears that selectedTextColor and selectedBgColor do not have any value because it does not change the color of the text or the background of the terminal. I'm trying not to use outside library since I'm doing bare metal programming in C in RPI3. Here is the link for references of the terminal color :
typedef struct color {
    const char *colorName;
    const char *textColor;
    const char *bgColor;
} color;

color color_values[] = {
    {"black", "30", "40"},
    {"red", "31", "41"},
    {"green", "32", "42"},
    {"yellow", "33", "43"},
    {"blue", "34", "44"},
    {"purple", "35", "45"},
    {"cyan", "36", "46"},
    {"white", "37", "47"},
    {"none","hello","hi"}
};



// color code to color name
const char* get_color_code(const char* color, int is_background) {
    for (int i = 0; my_strcmp(color_values[i].colorName, "none") != 0; i++) {
        if (my_strcmp(color_values[i].colorName, color) == 0) {
            return is_background ? color_values[i].bgColor : color_values[i].textColor;
        }
    }
    return "0";  // Return default "reset" color if no match found
}

void selectColor() {
    char colorInput[MAX_CMD_SIZE];
    int inputIndex;
    char command;
    const char *selectedTextColor;
    const char *selectedBgColor;
    char c;

    while ((c = uart_getc()) != '\n') {
        uart_sendc(c); // Echo the character back to the terminal

        if (c == ' ') {
            if (command == 't') {
                colorInput[inputIndex] = '\0';
                selectedTextColor = get_color_code(colorInput, 0);
            } else if (command == 'b') {
                colorInput[inputIndex] = '\0';
                selectedBgColor = get_color_code(colorInput, 1);
            }
            command = 0;
            inputIndex = 0;
        } else if (c == '-') {
            c = uart_getc(); // Read the next character to check if it's 't' or 'b'
            uart_sendc(c); // Echo it
            if (c == 't' || c == 'b') {
                command = c;
            }
            continue; // Skip storing '-' and the following character
        } else if (command) {
            colorInput[inputIndex++] = c;
        }
    }

    if (my_strcmp(selectedTextColor, "0") != 0) {
        uart_puts("\033[");
        uart_puts(selectedTextColor);
        uart_puts("m");
    }
    if (my_strcmp(selectedBgColor, "0") != 0) {
        uart_puts("\033[");
        uart_puts(selectedBgColor);
        uart_puts("m");
    }
}


The code doesn't initialize  the varaibles, so if something surprising arrives - like a space for the first uart read - command and InputIndex have unknown values.

What you need is some debugging. Add logs or whatever is more convenient to understand the values coming from the UART, whether the function get_color_code() is being invoked, and what it returns. There seem to be a lot of code paths that would lead to that function call being skipped and then those variables would be uninitialized and the program won't yield expected values.
